# How to create a positional argument with "local" option with clap?

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, clap

I am trying to create something like this with Clap:

```
cli-test --color "red" "rose" --color "yellow" "tulip" ...
```

I.e., a positional argument (the flower) which can occur multiple times with an assigned/"local" option (the color).

Is this possible with Clap? And if yes, how can I achieve it?

I have tried an argument of type struct:

```
use clap::Parser;

#[derive(Parser)]
#[command(
    name = env!("CARGO_PKG_NAME"),
    version = env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION"),
    author = env!("CARGO_PKG_AUTHORS"),
    about = env!("CARGO_PKG_DESCRIPTION")
)]
struct Args {
    flower_args: Vec<FlowerArgs>,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct FlowerArgs {
    #[arg(long = "color", help = "Color of the flower", num_args(1))]
    color: Vec<Option<String>>,
    flowers: Vec<String>,
}

pub fn main() {
    let args = Args::parse();

    // TODO
}
```

But this leads to various errors:

```
   |
16 |     #[arg(long = "color", help = "Color of the flower", num_args(1))]
   |       ^^^

error[E0599]: the method `value_parser` exists for reference `&&&&&&_AutoValueParser<FlowerArgs>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
    --> src/main.rs:11:5
     |
11   |     flower_args: Vec<FlowerArgs>,
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `&&&&&&_AutoValueParser<FlowerArgs>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
...
15   | struct FlowerArgs {
     | -----------------
     | |
     | doesn't satisfy `FlowerArgs: From<&'s std::ffi::OsStr>`
     | doesn't satisfy `FlowerArgs: From<&'s str>`
     | doesn't satisfy `FlowerArgs: From<OsString>`
     | doesn't satisfy `FlowerArgs: From<std::string::String>`
     | doesn't satisfy `FlowerArgs: FromStr`
     | doesn't satisfy `FlowerArgs: ValueEnum`
     | doesn't satisfy `FlowerArgs: ValueParserFactory`
     |
    ::: /home/mipi/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/clap_builder-4.2.1/src/builder/value_parser.rs:2221:1
     |
2221 | pub struct _AutoValueParser<T>(std::marker::PhantomData<T>);
     | ------------------------------ doesn't satisfy `_: _ValueParserViaParse`
     |
     = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
             `FlowerArgs: ValueEnum`
             which is required by `&&&&&_AutoValueParser<FlowerArgs>: clap::builder::via_prelude::_ValueParserViaValueEnum`
             `FlowerArgs: ValueParserFactory`
             which is required by `&&&&&&_AutoValueParser<FlowerArgs>: clap::builder::via_prelude::_ValueParserViaFactory`
             `FlowerArgs: From<OsString>`
             which is required by `&&&&_AutoValueParser<FlowerArgs>: clap::builder::via_prelude::_ValueParserViaFromOsString`
             `FlowerArgs: From<&'s std::ffi::OsStr>`
             which is required by `&&&_AutoValueParser<FlowerArgs>: clap::builder::via_prelude::_ValueParserViaFromOsStr`
             `FlowerArgs: From<std::string::String>`
             which is required by `&&_AutoValueParser<FlowerArgs>: clap::builder::via_prelude::_ValueParserViaFromString`
             `FlowerArgs: From<&'s str>`
             which is required by `&_AutoValueParser<FlowerArgs>: clap::builder::via_prelude::_ValueParserViaFromStr`
             `FlowerArgs: FromStr`
             which is required by `_AutoValueParser<FlowerArgs>: clap::builder::via_prelude::_ValueParserViaParse`
note: the traits `ValueEnum`, `ValueParserFactory`, `From`,  and `FromStr` must be implemented
    --> /home/mipi/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/clap_builder-4.2.1/src/builder/value_parser.rs:2124:1
     |
2124 | pub trait ValueParserFactory {
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
    ::: /home/mipi/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/clap_builder-4.2.1/src/derive.rs:264:1
     |
264  | pub trait ValueEnum: Sized + Clone {
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
    ::: /home/mipi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/convert/mod.rs:543:1
     |
543  | pub trait From<T>: Sized {
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
    ::: /home/mipi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/str/traits.rs:547:1
     |
547  | pub trait FromStr: Sized {
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     = note: this error originates in the macro `clap::value_parser` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Comment: I can't help you with your problem per se, but do you think it's the best option to go with?  I mean I personally would be confused encountering such CLI design.  I tend to go with something like `--colour "red:rose"`, that seems a clearer idea to me personally.  It's quite possible that CLI libraries/frameworks can't easily handle cases like yours.